# what programming languages support lazy evaluation?

Tags: lazy-evaluation

I would like to try out lazy expression evaluation, but I do not want to dive into Haskel right now. Please, can you help to find what other languages have this feature?

Comment: Which paradigm do you want? Functional or not?

Comment: SliceSort, functional probably, but I am not sure. I prefer learning things from trying real programming language rather than reading articles and theory papers.

Comment: cutest avatar ever. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could simulate it in many languages. [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/682455/Generic-Lazy-Evaluation-in-Cplusplus) is a generic lazy evaluator for C++, for example. As the article says, its also supported by .NET languages (Thats what the article is trying to emulate).
C++ expression templates are other form of lazy evaluation, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Python's generators are lazy.

Any dataflow language is lazy.

There's also [Lazy Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/lazy/). Racket is a Scheme derivative.

SWI Prolog has [`freeze` predicate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=freeze/2), which suspends evaluation on a logical variable until it is needed, making possible e.g. this:

```erlang
fibs(X):- X = [0,1|Z], genfibs(X, Z).

genfibs([A|Y], Z):- Y = [B|Z], freeze(Z, (C is A+B, Z = [C|W], genfibs(Y, W))).
```

Testing:

> 13 ?- fibs(X), length(A,15), append(A,_,X), writeln(A). 
>   
>   ***[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377]***   
>  
>   <sub>freeze(_G2517, (_G2582 is 233+377, _G2517=[_G2582|_G2595], genfibs([377|_G2517], _G2595))).</sub>

This is a translation of Haskell's

```hs
fibs = x where x = 0 : 1 : (gen x)
               gen (a: y@(b:_)) = (a+b) : (gen y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lazy evaluation is useful in two cases:
(1) You work with infinite lists,
(2) You need answer *before* question.

This is normal in functional programming (f.e.: Gofer/Miranda/Haskell).

An infinite list can be seen as a stream (as keyboard input, random numbers, music from radio, ...)

Examples:
(a) Natural numbers: [1..]
(b) Fibonacci numbers:
fibs = 0:1: zipwith (+) fibs (tl fibs)

If you want to get 20 random numbers, you will express this as:
take 20 randoms

In "normal" (imperative) coding style, user dialogs are of form:
...->(input->output)->(input->output)->...

In functional programming (FP), the view is changed to:
...->input)->(output->input)->(output->...

This is only possible using lazy evaluation.

If you are running Linux, you can compile and run Miranda from miranda.org.uk. Miranda was commercial. It is much easier than Haskell.

foldr1 (+) [1..36]

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't forget **Clean** !( https://wiki.clean.cs.ru.nl/Clean ). Essentially similar to Haskell (laziness, type inference, a good part of syntax). Plenty of interchangeability, see e.g.,
https://www.mbsd.cs.ru.nl/publications/papers/2010/groj10-Haskell_front_end_Clean.pdf

The type system is a bit different, perhaps less sophisticated than in Haskell (the type class system is "flatter", no monads [unless user implemented], but "unique types" replace monads in a readable and efficient way.)

This is a nice, useful language which should be better known, and taught. In my opinion: for numerical work it is easier to handle complex algorithms than in Haskell. And it is very efficient.